# PHP Mail with UTF-8, Strange behaviour

Tags: php, email, encoding

I have the following function:

```
function mail_utf8($to="test@domain.com", $from_user="domain.com", $from_email="pageinfo@domain.com",$subject = 'äüß', $message = 'äöü')
{
  $headers =
           "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n" .
           "Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n"
           ."From: $from_user <$from_email>\r\n";

  return mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
```

and i run this function with standard parameter. The strange thing is, the subject is displayed well in the mail client, but the message part is not interpreted as utf-8. How comes this and what do i need to do against it?

Comment: The PHP-Document itself is utf8, too

Comment: _Don't_ try to create the mail-headers yourself (unless you've read and understood all RFCs for them), use a Mailer-Class.

Comment: OK, did that now. Thank you. Still do not understand the problem, but idc now.